# How to open Ethernet settings programatically?

Tags: android, android-intent, ethernet, android-settings

The way to open the Wi-Fi settings is the following:

```
startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_WIFI_IP_SETTINGS));
```

Is there an equivalent way for the Ethernet settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally in all android device (not custom android) Settings.ACTION_ETHERNET_IP_SETTINGS kind of Intent not available for ETHERNET.

It is depending on custom android OS. If it provide that kind of Intent in there android OS.than you can use it.

Comment: It did not found in my android sdk while i am using TV device that have ETHERNET setting.